# Python rsa module troubles

Tags: python, python-3.x, rsa

I need to encrypt some data, so I decided to use rsa module. I need to generate public and private keys. I want to send my public keys to some clients. How can I do this?

```
import rsa
(public_key, private_key) = rsa.newkeys(512)
```

So I've already generated it, but `public_key` now is a structure with two fields `e` and `n`. how can I transform it into bytes? And back from bytes to such structure?

Comment: You could use pickle?

Comment: Yes, if the other clients are written in python you can use pickle. The answer to this depends entirely on what formats the other clients support.

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk yes the client is written in Python. But what is pickle?

Comment: Look it up in the python docs. If this is pyrsa it also has load and save methods for the public key and the private key that are probably more appropriate.

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk I have already watched, but I use queue messages, so I can't send files, only strings

Comment: Then use the `save_pkcs1` method with `PEM` format. That returns the encoding of a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PyCrypto module

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
key = RSA.generate(512)
private_key = key.exportKey(passphrase='', pkcs=8)
public_key = key.publickey().exportKey()
```

In your case, try using `save_pkcs1` method for saving into PEM format.

UPD:

Code sample for encrypt using rsa:

```
message = b'message'
# Alternative way - message = 'message'.encode('utf-8')
encrypted = rsa.encrypt(message, public_key)
```

For decrypt:

```
rsa.decrypt(encrypted, private_key).decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: I don't think he's using PyCrypto.

Comment: I tried to use PyCrypto, but in this case, I got an error when crypt and decrypt message. Because I use python 3

Comment: So can you show please how to encrypt the message if we know the public key?